# React componentDidMount setState but return undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can get list with get axios.get method. then ı can use setState and it works flawlessly.
but the return is not true , its return undefined console.log(result) => undefined . How can ı check if setState work fine return true or return false ?

```
getList = async () => {
  await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/list").then((response) => {
    this.setState(
      {
        copy: response.data.list,
      },
      () => {
        return true;
      },
    );
  });
};

componentDidMount = () => {
  this.getList().then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  });
};
```

Comment: What exactly is the error message you get? You are  calling `this.getlist`, but `getLIst` is an async function, but it doesn't return anything. I would expect that the result of `await this.getList()` is `undefined`

Comment: `setState`'s return value does not matter. `setState` always works (unless something is very broken).

Comment: @dwjohnston I don't get any error, just console.log is undefined.

Comment: @zafer that makes sense. You aren't returning anything from you `getList` function

Comment: `getList` doesn't return anything, neither does the final `then` in the axios promise chain

Comment: @dwjohnston ok how can ı check request is list come or dont come

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `return true` statement is in `setState`'s post-set callback. It won't be propagated to the promise that's returned from `getList`; indeed, you return nothing from that function (you don't even return the Axios promise; if you did return that, you would get the response logged in your `console.log`, but it would be logged before the `setState` callback finished), so you get `undefined` in the `console.log`.

If you need `getList` to return a promise that resolves to `true` once the state has been set, you'll need

```
getList = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) =>
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/list").then((response) =>
      this.setState(
        {
          copy: response.data.list,
        },
        () => resolve(true),
      ),
    ),
  );
};

componentDidMount = () => {
  this.getList().then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to set state can `return true` but, it's not going anywhere. You need to somehow use it, example:

```
const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/list")

return new Promise((resolve) => {
  this.setState({
    copy : response.data.list
  }, () => {
    resolve(true);
  })
})
```

now the chain will work because you are resolving the promise chain with `true` instead of returning it from the callback function